# I change the model values in the controller but the view receives the model with the old values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this action:

```
//Edit
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult InvoiceType(clsInvoiceType Model, string Stade)
{
    Model.Stade = Stade== "1" ? true : false;
    return PartialView(Model);
}
```

In this action I try to change the value for `Model.Stade` and return the model but the view receive always the values sent to this action, the problem is that I try to change the value of model here in the action and return the new model values to the view but the view receive the original model values so my changes is not working, what is the problem?

How can I change the original model values and send them to the view?

Comment: Just put the breakpoint into this action and observe what will happen step by step.

Comment: Possibly it's the cached data being returned? Show us the markup from where you are calling the ActionResult `InvoiceType`.

Comment: I did it, in the action the value change but when the model is sent to the view this recieve the original values, so my changes is not working

Comment: This is the code where I call the action:

Comment: function Edit(Id) {
            var row = jQuery("#Grid").jqGrid('getRowData', Id);
            $("#Detail").load('@Url.Action("/" + "TipoFactura",      "TipoFactura")', row);
        };

Comment: Can you please edit you original question with the updated code? It seems to me like you code in comment and the post doesn't match.

Answer (score 1):

The [`ModelState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.modelstate(v=vs.118).aspx) object contains the values that were posted back to your action method.  The `Html.*For()` helper methods in your view will always pull values from the `ModelState` before looking at the actual vaules in your model.  If you want to change a value you need to remove the posted value from the `ModelState`.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult InvoiceType(clsInvoiceType Model, string Stade)
{
    this.ModelState.Remove("Stade");  // or .Clear() to remove all keys
    Model.Stade = Stade== "1" ? true : false;
    return PartialView(Model);
}
```

Comment: thanks, this work but this line this.ModelState.Remove("Stade") can generate problem with the helpers? for example if the view has a helper that use this value, can the helper to get it?

Comment: No, the helpers, when populating values, will look first in the ModelState collection for a value for the key, if its not found in the ModelState collection, then it will pull the value from the model object.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should disable caching by:

```
[OutputCache(Duration=0, VaryByParam="none")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult InvoiceType(clsInvoiceType Model, string Stade)
{
    Model.Stade = Stade== "1" ? true : false;
    return PartialView(Model);
}
```